# Crop and Upload image in Codeigniter

Tags: image, codeigniter, image-uploading, crop

In one of my project I want to allow user to upload his/her photo in profile. In times of uploading the photo i want to allow them to crop image as per their choice and when they click on update profile button i want to upload only that cropped image as their profile image. I am developing this application in CI. Can anyone help me how can i do this. I have used jquery.Jcrop.js library to crop image. I am able to crop image using below code but when i click on update button then it will upload original image not cropped image.

```
<input type="file" href="#" class="selectBtn loginlink image_class" name="profilepic" id="profilepic" onChange="fileSelectHandler()"> 
<img id="preview" />
<input type="hidden" class="info1" id="filesize" name="filesize" />
<input type="hidden"  class="info1" id="filetype" name="filetype" />
<input type="hidden"  class="info1" id="filedim" name="filedim" />
<input type="hidden" class="info1" id="w" name="w" />
<input type="hidden" class="info1" id="h" name="h" />
<input type="hidden" id="x1" name="x1" />
<input type="hidden" id="y1" name="y1" />
<input type="hidden" id="x2" name="x2" />
<input type="hidden" id="y2" name="y2" />
```

below is javascript code to crop image

```
function bytesToSize(bytes) {
var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB'];
if (bytes == 0)
    return 'n/a';
var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
return (bytes / Math.pow(1024, i)).toFixed(1) + ' ' + sizes[i];
```

}
;

```
// check for selected crop region
function checkForm() {
if (parseInt($('#w').val()))
    return true;
    $('.error').html('Please select a crop region and then press    Upload').show();
return false;
}
;

// update info by cropping (onChange and onSelect events handler)
function updateInfo(e) {
$('#x1').val(e.x);
$('#y1').val(e.y);
$('#x2').val(e.x2);
$('#y2').val(e.y2);
$('#w').val(e.w);
$('#h').val(e.h);
}
;

// clear info by cropping (onRelease event handler)
function clearInfo() {
$('.info #w').val('');
$('.info #h').val('');
}
;

// Create variables (in this scope) to hold the Jcrop API and image size
var jcrop_api, boundx, boundy;


function fileSelectHandler() {
// get selected file
var oFile = $('#image_file')[0].files[0];
// hide all errors
$('.error').hide();
// check for image type (jpg and png are allowed)
var rFilter = /^(image\/jpeg|image\/png)$/i;
if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) {
    $('.error').html('Please select a valid image file (jpg and png are allowed)').show();
    return;
}
// check for file size
if (oFile.size > 250 * 1024) {
    $('.error').html('You have selected too big file, please select a one smaller image file').show();
    return;
}
if (oFile.size < 300 * 300) {
    $('.error').html('You have selected too small file, please select a one bigger image file').show();
    return;
}
// preview element
var oImage = document.getElementById('preview');
// prepare HTML5 FileReader
var oReader = new FileReader();
oReader.onload = function (e) {
    // e.target.result contains the DataURL which we can use as a source of the image
    oImage.src = e.target.result;
    oImage.onload = function () { // onload event handler
        // display step 2
        $('.step2').fadeIn(500);
        // display some basic image info
        var sResultFileSize = bytesToSize(oFile.size);
        $('#filesize').val(sResultFileSize);
        $('#filetype').val(oFile.type);
        $('#filedim').val(oImage.naturalWidth + ' x ' + oImage.naturalHeight);
        // destroy Jcrop if it is existed
        if (typeof jcrop_api != 'undefined') {
            jcrop_api.destroy();
            jcrop_api = null;
            $('#preview').width(oImage.naturalWidth);
            $('#preview').height(oImage.naturalHeight);
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            // initialize Jcrop
            $('#preview').Jcrop({
                minSize: [32, 32], // min crop size
                aspectRatio: 1, // keep aspect ratio 1:1
                bgFade: true, // use fade effect
                bgOpacity: .3, // fade opacity
                onChange: updateInfo,
                onSelect: updateInfo,
                onRelease: clearInfo
            }, function () {
                // use the Jcrop API to get the real image size
                var bounds = this.getBounds();
                boundx = bounds[0];
                boundy = bounds[1];
                // Store the Jcrop API in the jcrop_api variable
                jcrop_api = this;
            });
        }, 3000);
    };
};
// read selected file as DataURL
oReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}
```

Below is my controller code

```
$config1['upload_path'] = './mobileapps/supporter/upimages/candidate/images/';
                $config1['allowed_types'] = '*';
                $config1['encrypt_name'] = true;
                $this->load->library('upload', $config1);
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload('profilepic')) {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    print_r($error);
                    exit;
                } else {
                    $image_data = $this->upload->data();

                    $image = $image_data['file_name'];
                    $target1 = './mobileapps/supporter/upimages/candidate/images/' . $image;
$config1['source_image'] = $config1['upload_path'] . '/' .     $image_data['file_name'];
$config1['x_axis'] = $this->input->post('x1');
$config1['y_axis'] = $this->input->post('y1');
$config1['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
$config1['width'] = $this->input->post('w');
                    $config1['height'] = $this->input->post('h');
                    $config1['quality'] = '90%';
                    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config1);
                    if (!$this->image_lib->crop()) {
                        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                    }else{
                        echo 'else';
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this codeIngiter Image manipulation. Hopefully work. It's work on me

```
$config['image_library'] = 'imagemagick';
$config['library_path'] = '/usr/X11R6/bin/';
$config['source_image'] = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';
$config['x_axis'] = 100;
$config['y_axis'] = 60;

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);

if ( ! $this->image_lib->crop())
 {
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
 }
```

Comment: I have use this but still it upload original image only.

Comment: I have added my controller code please check and let me know where i make mistake.